# How can I get the a lambda function by using its ARN in the AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I'm using the Azure Toolkit for AWS to create my lambda, and then running some powershell scripts to act on it. After creation, I get the function's ARN as an output. I don't see anywhere in the [documentation](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lambda/index.html#cli-aws-lambda) where I can access the function via the ARN, everything takes the `function-name` as a parameter.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I asked this shortly before I was off for the holidays and just now came back to see the obvious answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ARN in the `--function-name` parameter when executing AWS CLI calls for the AWS lambda API.

Here's an example for the [get-function api](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lambda/get-function.html#options):

> --function-name (string)

```
The name of the Lambda function, version, or alias.

Name formats

Function name - my-function (name-only), my-function:v1 (with alias).

Function ARN - arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:123456789012:function:my-function .

Partial ARN - 123456789012:function:my-function
```

Comment: I feel dumb for not noticing this! Thank you!